# Unable to properly wire timer to old light switch with one “white?” Wire on top and one looped black wire

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, timer

Top wire is painted white. bottom wire is looped. Timer has screws for line, load, neutral and ground. What goes where?

[image]

[image]

I am getting power but only half the light output with one part of black loop in line and the other in load and the “White’ In neutral. I have tried every combination i think. This is in a 3 switch box and one black wire runs to the next Boxswitch. That light works!

Comment: You have line and load there.  You need neutral, Show is a picture looking into the back of the box.

Comment: Thanks. Added picture of junction box. It is messy! And i cannot move timer farther out unless i unwire. Everything inside seems to be connected

Comment: That paint is just slop from painters/drywallers by the way -- it has no meaning re: wire color

Comment: Can you post a photo that shows the back of the rest of the box?

Comment: Do you want me to take other switch panels off? Thanks re white paint!! Nothing seems to be loose inside.

Comment: Plus i cut the looped wire in order to fit into timer. Whoops....

Comment: Is there a bundle of white wires into a wirenut in the back of the box? It looks like there darn well ought to be, but I can't see it

Comment: Yes there is. Also i just bought a timer that does not require neutral. Not sure if it works yet!

Comment: The new timer works! No neutral required. Thanks for advice particularly that the paint/ plaster did not matter!!

Answer (score 1):

The double wire is simply power being carried onward to other switches.

Note the solitary black wire.   Follow it to see which cable that wire departs the box in.  Now look at that cable's white wire and follow it back to a bundle of all-whites... Add your smarts witch neutral to that bundle.   Do not remove any wires from the bundle, they are not spares.

Do not add it to any random bundle of whites you see. That will "seem to work" until you add a GFCI or AFCI, then will trip it.   Add it to the right bundle.